# Set Button background colour from Android Studio

Tags: button

I put a small button and cannot find a way to set the background colour of small button from Android Studio.
What I did was:
- Properties window -> View -> Background

When I click the ellipses, there is no colours for selection.

What did I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the background color in xml like that:

```
<Button
        android:background="#e63e91"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        />
```

or you can set an image backgroud like that:
            **android:backgroud="@drawable/test.png"**